# Difference between the created and mounted events in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Vue.js documentation describes the `created` and `mounted` events as follows:

```
created
```

> Called synchronously after the instance is created. At this
>   stage, the instance has finished processing the options which means
>   the following have been set up: data observation, computed properties,
>   methods, watch/event callbacks. However, the mounting phase has not
>   been started, and the $el property will not be available yet.

```
mounted
```

> Called after the instance has just been mounted where el is replaced
>   by the newly created vm.$el. If the root instance is mounted to an
>   in-document element, vm.$el will also be in-document when mounted is
>   called.
>
> This hook is not called during server-side rendering.

I understand the theory, but I have **2 questions** regarding practice:

1. Is there any case where `created` would be used over `mounted`?
2. What can I use the `created` event for, in real-life (real-code)
   situation?

Comment: `created` is called earlier, so it makes sense to trigger data fetching from API backend for example.

Comment: Can confirm, the examples in Fullstack Vue book all use `created()` to dispatch actions for api calls.

Comment: @EgorStambakio What if i dont use created in my component and I use only mounted, is not almost the same in mounted to call the api?I mean that the created hook will be skipped since it wont be called.

Comment: @LastM4N you can do it in mounted, that's your choice. But because the hooks run synchronously, you want to do it in the right place. Since the API call has nothing to do with the DOM, it belongs in the created hook.

Comment: @wittgenstein ok we agree, although Vue official doc uses the mounted hook https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html

Answer (score 420, accepted):

`created()` : since the processing of the options is finished you have access to reactive `data` properties and change them if you want. At this stage DOM has not been mounted or added yet. So you cannot do any DOM manipulation here

`mounted()`: called after the DOM has been mounted or rendered. Here you have access to the DOM elements and DOM manipulation can be performed for example get the innerHTML:

```
console.log(element.innerHTML)
```

So your questions:

1. `Is there any case where created would be used over mounted?`

Created is generally used for fetching data from backend API and setting it to data properties. But in SSR `mounted()` hook is not present you need to perform tasks like fetching data in created hook only

2. `What can I use the created event for, in real-life (real-code) situation?`

For fetching any initial required data to be rendered(like JSON) from external API and  assigning it to any reactive data properties

```
data:{
    myJson : null,
    errors: null
},
created(){
    //pseudo code
    database.get().then((res) => {
        this.myJson = res.data;
    }).catch((err) => {
        this.errors = err;
    });
}
```

Comment: When making api call in created does it wait for all of the async operations to complete before moving on to the next life cycle stage?

Comment: @Ominus no it does not wait,  Run this fiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/1k26sqrx/] and check out the console logs

Comment: I've noticed that when mounted() is used instead of created(). Vue tests if the reactive variable set, really exists as reactie variable. If not, an error is thrown. This is not the case in created() "Property or method "foo" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive."

Comment: So if it does not wait (per @Omnius comment) what is the added value of `created` for data fetching? It may be that the data starts to be fetched in `created` and once Vue moves to  the mount stage, they still won't be there (and errors will be thrown)

Comment: @WoJ For that reason you should have a loading flag and use this flag to show a loader until the data is fetched.

Comment: @WoJ - it's best to fetch data as early as possible, not after the DOM has been rendered

Comment: But then, why don't people do everything in created? Isn't it quite rare to use DOM properties? Said in another way, if I don't have any use of the DOM, should I use created?

Comment: @tobiasBora as long as you do not need to interact with DOM, created should do

Comment: @VamsiKrishna ok thanks. Also, if you create several object, I guess that `created` will be called as many times as there are objects, like `mounted`.

Comment: @tobiasBora by several objects if you mean multiple due instances, yes every vuue instance will call it's respective `created ` hook. But `created` is  called only once when a due object is instantiated.

Comment: @VamsiKrishna ok thanks... But sometimes it's possible to keep an object in cache even if it's destroyed... does that mean that in that case mount can be called several times while created will be called only once (per this specific instance)?

Comment: @tobiasBora yes, it's called only once

Comment: @VamsiKrishna fiddle no longer working - returns `404`.

Comment: Mounted has the word "DOM" in it.  Created has "A"jax or "A"xios. Now you will never forget.

Answer (score -3):

For the `created()` hook, the data after manipulation in the browser it not shown in the DOM before mounted. In simple words the data takes time to manipulate the DOm seen the browser .

The `mounted()` hook is called after the DOM has been mounted or rendered which enables you to have access to the DOM elements and you can perform DOM manipulation.The best use for the mounted hook is if you need to access the DOM immediately before or after the initial render.

Comment: You are rehashing an existing answer.

Comment: I did'n rehash any existing answer

Comment: Yes... you did.