# How to trigger an event inside the Created method?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to get the GET param's value and trigger an event. How to trigger an event inside the Created method?

I tried this way, but click method is not found:

```
created(){
    if(this.$route.query.text!=''){
        this.textToTranslate = this.$route.query.text;
        const elem = this.$refs.languageSelect;
        elem.change();
    }
  },
```

Comment: try in `mounted` instead `created`

Comment: refs are not available until `mounted` because they are references to created DOM elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `mounted` since you're interacting with DOM elements, those elements won't be available inside the `created` lifecycle hook. For more information: [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js).