# VueJs Axios - Request headers

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

Edit: Could this be a CORS issue, I'm on localhost...

In Javascript I can set the request headers and get and return a response like so:

```
    $(function() {
    var params = {
        // Request parameters
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: "https://demo-api.com/",
        beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{API KEY}");
        },
        type: "GET",
        // Request body
        data: "{body}",
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function() {
        alert("error");
    });
});
```

**Question:**

I want to learn VueJs and would like replicate this with **VueJs + Axios**, however I am confused as to **how to set the request headers** as I have in the above JS.

**Here is my failed attempt:**

```
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data () {
        return {
          info: null,
          loading: true,
          errored: false,
          response: false
        }
      },
      mounted () {
          axios({
              method: 'get',
              url: 'https://demo-api.com/',
              headers: { 
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'API KEY',
              } 
            })
            .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
              this.response = true
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              this.errored = true
            })
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
        }
    })
```

How can I specifically set the **request headers** as I have in the above JS. I am wanting to learn how to implement the below in Vue/Axios.

```
 xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","{API KEY}");
```

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set header and options in axios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578844/how-to-set-header-and-options-in-axios)

Comment: @Vucko I have used that as a reference point, however this is yielding a 404 response. My concern was, am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I suggest you to think over the usage of jquery + vuejs combo.
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Comment: @LakiGeri could you elaborate further? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Difference between the created and mounted events in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js)

Read an answer and try to use `created()` lifecycle hooks instead of `mounted()`

Furthermore, you can create separate instance of axios for request with this header and then use it inn you code:

```
axios-demo-api.js

import axios from 'axios'

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://demo-api.com',
    headers: {'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': 'API KEY'} //don't forget to change API key to your exact key
})

export default instance
```

Usage:

```
import axiosInstance from 'axios-demo-api';


export default {

 created() {
  axiosInstance.get('/{demoId}?' + $.param(params))
                .then(response => {
              console.log(response)
              this.response = true
            })
            .catch(error => {
              console.log(error)
              this.errored = true
            })
            .finally(() => this.loading = false)
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @vladja. I am only starting out learning so appreciate your response here. I amended my code to this snippet, which then returns a 404: https://jsfiddle.net/hx74u851/1/

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the header. You are setting it properly. It has to do with the URL. You are constructing your URL like this:

```
url: 'https://demo-api.com/{demoId}?" + $.param(params)',
```

Your URL string is wrong. It has an extra quote at the end. That's why you got 404 error. This is what you need to do:

```
url: "https://demo-api.com/{demoId}?" + $.param(params),
```

Also, if you are using Vue and not jQuery, then you should not use `$.param` function. Instead, use a proper query string module like [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs). So your actual URL would be like:

```
url: `https://demo-api.com/${demoId}?${qs.stringify(params)}`,
```

Here we are using ES2015 string interpolation.

Comment: @Thanks, I have updated my code to remove that.The response is still returning a 404.