# Which life cycle hook is best practise to dispatch an API fetch request with?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm just wondering if there is currently a consensus within the Vue.js community as to which life cycle hook to use for dispatching an API fetch action?

For example, I have an action such as in my `Vuex` store:

```
  ...
  actions: {
    fetchAccount: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
      await Vue.prototype.$API.fetchAccount(payload).then((response) => {
        commit("SET_ACTIVE_ACCOUNT", response.data);
      });
    },
  }
  ...
```

The action gets passed off to a service:

```
import { axios } from "@/services/http";
import { EventEmitter } from "events";

class accountServiceAPI extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.accessToken = "";
  }

  fetchAccount(payload) {
    return new Promise({resolve, reject} => {
      axiosWave.get(`api//v2/accounts/retrieve/${payload.accountUUID}`, { headers: {} }).then(response => {
        if (response.success) {
          resolve(response.data);
        } else {
          reject(response.data);
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        reject(error.response);
      });
    });
  }
}

const accountServiceAPI = new accountServiceAPI();

accountServiceAPI.setMaxListeners(5);

export default accountServiceAPI;
```

I usualy dispatch this off in the `created()` life cycle hook for the component that the data is required to be for...but surely there must be a more performant way?

Comment: it is exactly where I would do it. But I would not mix `aync/await` and `then`.

Comment: however, if your whole app depends on this, you can wrap the whole application in it before initializing it.

Comment: @oshell Is there any different between using `mount()` and `created()` or even `beforeCreate()` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js

Comment: https://vuejs.org/images/lifecycle.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch from API and manipulate your data/state as early as in `created()`. `mounted()` is called when the instance has already, well, mounted or rendered. You'll usually do UI-related setup here.

Also, you can improve the `fetchAccount` action like so:

```js
fetchAccount: async ({ commit }, payload) => {
  const { data } = await Vue.prototype.$API.fetchAccount(payload);
  commit("SET_ACTIVE_ACCOUNT", data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alphonsus, appreciate your answer on this.