# How to define a starting point in a v-for loop in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a group of fields that are generated in a loop an indefinite number of times. Basically 2 input fields, a label, and a delete button. Then another button that says Add More.

Every time they hit that, one more set of the above-mentioned appears. They can do this as many times as they want. It looks like this. (I'm using quasar, hence why the q-"" elements)

```
// Click more button
<q-btn @click="onAddBarcodes" icon="add" no-caps color="primary">Add More</q-btn>


// Form
<div v-for="(barcode, index) in barcodes" :key="index">
    <div class="row q-pr-lg items-center">
        <div class="col-3">
             <label class="text-weight-medium">Starting Roll #:</label>
             <q-input v-model="barcode.start" :id="barcode.id"></q-input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
             <label class="text-weight-medium">Ending Roll #:</label>
             <q-input v-model="barcode.end" :id="barcode.id"></q-input>
        </div>
        <div class="col-5">
             <label class="text-weight-medium">Agency Name:</label>
             <div v-if="barcode.agencyName">
                 {{ barcode.agencyName }}
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
             <q-btn @click="onDeleteBarcodes(barcode.id)" icon="close"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


export default {
    data() {
        return {
            barcodes: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onAddBarcodes() {
            const newBarcode = {
                id: Math.random() * Math.random() * 1000,
                start: "",
                end: "",
                agencyName: ""
            };
            this.barcodes.push(newBarcode);
        },
        onDeleteBarcodes(id) {
            this.barcodes = this.barcodes.filter(barcode => barcode.id !== id);
        },
    }
 }
```

Now this works at its most basic form. What I want to do is to load the component with a set number of iterations already started. For example, 5 of them.

The Add More button will add the 6th on forward if they need more. The delete button should delete down to zero if they wanted to (not that they would) but it should definitely delete down to 1 at least.

How can I start the `v-for` at a specific number of iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add 5 items to `barcodes` on [`created()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks) vue instance like:

```
created() {
    [...Array(5).keys()].forEach(() => this.onAddBarcodes())
}
```

Comment: At first, I thought Anurag had a very simple answer, but this one is much simpler plus I am already using onAddBarcodes in my created lifecycle, so this will work even simpler, cleaner and more efficient for me

Comment: You can also checkout [Difference between the created and mounted events in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js). Its always got to bookmark these great content for future refrences.

Comment: Nice, and I thought mine was the shortest :)

Comment: I have not tested this, but I think we can make it even shorter like: `[...Array(5).keys()].forEach(this.onAddBarcodes)`. @LOTUSMS could you please verify this once.

Comment: This one also works for OP's purpose because they don't need values: `[...new Array(n)].forEach()`

Comment: @palaѕн Correct! The even shorter version also worked

Answer (score 1):

You can add mounted hook and initialize collection with 5 elements here

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            barcodes: []
        }
    },
    mounted() {
     this.barcodes = Array(5).fill(0).map(pr => ({
                id: Math.random() * Math.random() * 1000,
                start: "",
                end: "",
                agencyName: ""
            }))
    },
    methods: {
        onAddBarcodes() {
            const newBarcode = {
                id: Math.random() * Math.random() * 1000,
                start: "",
                end: "",
                agencyName: ""
            };
            this.barcodes.push(newBarcode);
        },
        onDeleteBarcodes(id) {
            this.barcodes = this.barcodes.filter(barcode => barcode.id !== id);
        },
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the `onAddBarcodes` n times in `beforeMount`:

```
beforeMount(){
   const n = 5; // Or any number
   Array.from(new Array(n)).forEach(el => this.onAddBarcodes());
}
```