# Vue js watcher does not react to changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I've seen some questions about vue.js watchers, but i didnt find a question handling my problem, so here it is:

In my SomeComponent.vue i use this code:

```
...
props: ['value']
,
watch: {
    value(val) {
        console.log(val);
    }
},
```

In my parent vue page, that uses this component i use this, which is working:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <SomeComponent
            v-model="test"
        ></SomeComponent>
    </div>
</template>
data() {
    return {
        test: {}
    };
},
created() {
    this.test = this.DoSomething();
},
```

If i add another property the watcher is not triggered anymore:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <SomeComponent
            v-model="test"
        ></SomeComponent>
    </div>
</template>
data() {
    return {
        test: {}
    };
},
created() {
    this.test.Prop1 = this.DoSomething();
    this.test.Prop2 = "Test";
},
```

EDIT:
After Behappy's Answer my Component Part looks like this now:

```
...
props: ["value"],
watch: {
    value: {
        handler(val) {
            console.log(val);
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats):

> Due to limitations in JavaScript, there are types of changes that Vue cannot detect. However, there are ways to circumvent them to preserve reactivity.
>
> **For Objects**
>
> Vue cannot detect property addition or deletion. Since Vue performs the getter/setter conversion process during instance initialization, a property must be present in the `data` object in order for Vue to convert it and make it reactive. For example:

```
var vm = new Vue({
  data: {
    a: 1
  }
})
// `vm.a` is now reactive

vm.b = 2
// `vm.b` is NOT reactive
```

Vue does not allow dynamically adding new root-level reactive properties to an already created instance. However, it’s possible to add reactive properties to a nested object using the `this.$set(object, propertyName, value)` method:

In your case that would be:

```
created() {
    this.$set(this.test, 'Prop1', this.DoSomething())
    this.$set(this.test, 'Prop2', "Test")
},
```

Or, you can also assign a number of properties to an existing object, for example, using `Object.assign()` like:

```
this.test = Object.assign({}, this.test, { 'Prop1': 1, 'Prop2': 2 })
```

Answer (score 3):

This is because your `prop` is an `Object`.

For deeply watching you can do this:

```
watch: {
    value: {
        handler(val) {
          console.log(val);
        },
        deep: true
    }
},
```

and in `created` DOM is not rendered yet. So prop you sent to child component is not updated yet.[refer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45814848/8610127)

and as in other answers the correct way to change Object is to use `this.$set`:

```
  mounted() {
    this.$set(this.test, 'Prop1', this.DoSomething())
    this.$set(this.test, 'Prop2', 'Test')
  },
```

Comment: your welcome. and I think changing in `created` won't trigger `watch`, because value changes before sending to child component.