# Vue / Nuxt.js - APIs being called twice in created hook

Tags: api, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am currently developing in Nuxt.js and like most beginners, I wanted to know the best lifecycle hook to place API calls. Many resources I have found, much like the one below, state that the `created()` hook is the best place for fetching data from an API prior to having everything be loaded.

[Difference between the created and mounted events in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js)

My question came in when I noticed on the networking tab in developer options that my API within the `created()` hook was being called twice. After looking into this further, it states that this hook runs on server side and client side. I notice that `mounted()` only runs on client side so I am learning towards utilizing that hook. I did however notice that I can use some `if` logic (if process.server) in the `created()` hook to only have this run on the client / server and not both. Is this a common solution?

To clarify my question further, if `created()` runs on both server and client side, why put my API calls in this hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `created` might be an appropriate hook for Vue apps, Nuxt provides additional hooks that are better suited for fetching data. If you need the fetch to occur only on the server side, the call would need to be wrapped with `if(process.server)` within the hook.

#### [`fetch` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#the-fetch-hook)

1. Called during server-side rendering after the component instance is created, and on the client when navigating, but the [server-side fetch can be disabled](https://nuxtjs.org/blog/understanding-how-fetch-works-in-nuxt-2-12#disabling-fetch-on-server-side) with `fetchOnServer: false`.
2. Available in all Vue components
3. `this` context is available
4. Simply mutates the local data
5. Exposes the data loading status via `$fetchState.pending` and `$fetchState.error`, and allows manually invoking the `fetch` hook with `$fetch()`

*Example usage:*

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      todos: []
    }
  },
  async fetch() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`
    )
    // `todos` has to be declared in data()
    this.todos = data
  }
}
```

#### [`asyncData` hook](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#async-data)

1. Called before the component instance is created
2. Limited to only page-level components
3. `this` context is unavailable
4. Adds payload by returning the data

*Example usage:*

```js
export default {
  async asyncData(context) {
    const data = await context.$axios.$get(
      `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`
    )
    // `todos` does not have to be declared in data()
    return { todos: data.Item }
    // `todos` is merged with local data
  }
}
```