# Get value in methods and display in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm working with code in vuejs :

```
created() {
    var id = this.id
    axios
      .get("/api/product" + id)
      .then((res) => {
        this.rows = res.data;

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
 methods: {
  changeValue() {
    axios
      .get("/api/product" + id, {
        params: {
         status: this.status,
      },
       })
      .then((res) => {
        this.rows = res.data;

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
}
```

template :

```
<v-select
   :options="options"
   v-model="status"
   @input="changeValue()"
/>
```

My problem is when i get the `res.data` in my `methods` `this.rows = res.data`. When i `console.log(this.rows)` it shows the correct result i want to display.But it still shows `this.row` in `created()`.Is there a way to override this.rows in `created()`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think use `mounted` instead of `created` it's better load data when your component is ready so you can update DOM

> you can check this answer [Difference between the created and mounted events in Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45813347/difference-between-the-created-and-mounted-events-in-vue-js) for more details

also you need a variable/computed `options` as seen in template `:options=options`

```
 computed: {
   options() {
      // you can restructure you rows data to match what v-select requires
      return this.rows
   }
 },

 mounted() {
    var id = this.id
    axios
      .get("/api/product" + id)
      .then((res) => {
        this.rows = res.data;

      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created mostly used for logic which needs to be executed once at creation of the Vue instance. For this problem i recommend mounted as well because as the vue lifecycle diagram shows it is going to re run on specific data changes. e.g you change a key value in template.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram